# Suspicious accounts copying my bounty answer

Tags: support, flags, bounties, sock-puppets

I've just had quite unpleasant experience with this question:

[How can I highlight elements that match a regex in CKeditor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18728103/1768303)

First there was a guy who plainly copied/pasted my answer and got 2 instant up-votes. I warned him that I had flagged his answer, after what he deleted it and then down-voted a bunch of my own questions/answers, including that one. [Here is his deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18728103/how-can-i-highlight-elements-that-match-a-regex-in-ckeditor/21254925#21254925), which can be seen if you have >= 10K reps.

Now there's [another bloke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21259446/1768303) with a canned link and 2 up-votes.

What's the right way to deal with such activity?

Comment: Judging from what you say, this guy probably has sock puppet(s) upvoting his answer and downvoting yours. It is hard for a link only answer to get 2 instant upvotes when there are other answers, and downvoting needs 125 rep but he's got only 56 at the moment.

Comment: `and then down-voted a bunch of my own questions/answers,` How are you so sure?. I learnt to NEVER assume who votes as it is anonymous for a reason

Comment: @Tijesunimi You can guess that with a reasonable amount of certainty when you received consecutive downvotes on your posts some time after you leave a negative comment.

Comment: The guy who down-voted me is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2905706/dhipin-das). Apparently, he's now [moving his 350 reps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19927309/ios-linking-an-app-with-an-api) over to a buddy (or maybe fake) account to save them. Note the date of the question/answer. Another fraud?

Comment: @Tijesunimi, I was tracking his reputation going -1, -1, -1...

Comment: Ok, so every one of their questions/answers have at least +2 (often exactly +2) and they have 2 serial upvoting reversals?!

Comment: @RichardTingle, I haven't gone that deep with my analysis :) I've just reported him, the flag is still active.

Comment: If you think something fishy is going on, flag one of your answers, click "Other", and explain briefly what you think is going on.  Stick to facts and your assumptions, and identify specific users by linking to profile.  And let the mod look into it.  He will engage the SE team to look at the voting history if necessary.

Comment: Yup, smells of socks. Flagged the answer asking to nuke that sock.

Comment: @psubsee2003, a good advice, thank you.

Comment: Found [one of the socks](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2982255/kannan)

Comment: @AnirudhR, yep, that's the point. It's been a while since I replied to a bounty question, but I never experienced anything like this. Is it a brand new strategy?

Comment: @Noseratio Certainly looks like it. Only the mods can know for sure.

Comment: [Tutudoo has to be annother](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3056419/tutudoo). Annother one with the suspicious +2 to everything (even things that ended up at -1) and always on questions associated with Dhipin Das

Comment: @Noseratio  - No I've seen this strategy before. [For example here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812326/alternatives-for-automated-web-application-front-end-performance-testing/18977245#18977245) 10K users. Probably the upvote reversal / sock puppet delete script should check to see if any bounty rewards would still have been valid and automatically reverse them. I think it is probably a manual process at the moment.

Comment: What amazes me, these "masters of puppets" are apparently developers as well, aware of SQL etc. What are they thinking and whom are they trying to cheat?

Comment: @Noseratio And yet they make it excessively easy for us because they have answered on each others questions to get the accepts. If they were just a little less greedy and only answered on other questions and just upvoted with socks we'd never have found them all

Comment: I feel like your question title and the contents have become a little separated. Do you want us to discuss the implications of the bounty rules or help you with this particular situation (or both?)?

Comment: @Duncan, indeed I'd like to move on to a more generic discussion: *how it may be possible to improve the bounty system.* I do appreciate the help and support I've got for my particular case here.

Comment: @Noseratio: This is someone gaming the system. It's not the system that needs fixing here, I don't think, and you don't make any recommendations.

Comment: [dhipin-das:mission acomplished](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2905706/dhipin-das), [tutudoo:mission acomplished](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3056419/tutudoo), [kannan:mission acomplished](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2982255/kannan). All suspended/deleted

Comment: To your broader point, this is a pattern that we've seen before. I've caught a few people over the last couple of years that have used sock puppets or voting rings to come in and snipe bounties like this. I can't say if it's becoming more common, but it does happen. Some people will do what they can to exploit the rules of the system, whatever they are. I don't know that this necessarily means the half bounty for highest votes when a bounty hasn't been awarded is a bad design.

Comment: I've asked a follow on question regarding [the surviving bounty here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216963/active-bounties-allows-sock-puppet-gold-to-be-hoarded)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Highest voted and at least 2 up-votes for 1/2 bounty rule

The “Highest voted and at least 2 up-votes for 1/2 bounty” rule is only ever a fall back for if the bounty offerer fails to award the bounty, as such it is unlikely to have been a major contributor to the negative behaviour in this case, the bounty offerer will most likely award it manually.

### Suspicion of sock puppet behaviour

Where fraudulant behaviour is suspected the best thing to do is to flag under "other", explaining your suspicions and linking to suspected socks. Investigating these potential socks seems to suggest the +2 behaviour is normal to this group and so is likely unconnected to the bounty rules.

Comment: I'd also like to add that while it is fun for all of us to play "hunt the socks", opening a meta question and identifying specific users is usually not the best practice.  You have to consider the fact that you might be wrong and you may finger an innocent person.

Comment: @psubsee2003 true, although this question started off being about how the 2 votes for an auto bounty could cause problems.  The sock puppetry fell out of the investigation surrounding that